# Is the tag "ux-design" needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-blacklist-request

The tag [ux-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-design) doesn't sound like one we need, because this site is all about UX itself. Should it be removed?

Comment: Hrm I could have swore we nuked this exact tag or something very much like it a while ago. My vote's definitely to blacklist it

Comment: Related: [Is “website-design” a useful tag?](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/is-website-design-a-useful-tag)

Comment: @Ben, maybe you're thinking of [user-interaction](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/573/is-user-interaction-a-useful-tag)

Comment: This question is now a 'Hot Meta Post' but moderators haven't removed the tag yet, even though everyone agrees it should be nuked. When will it be deleted? [Probably in 6 to 8 weeks...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

Comment: @BenBrocka or another moderator, when is this tag going to be nuked?

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards Mods individually don't have the power to nuke a tag as that requires blacklisting the input to prevent it being suggested again in future. And blacklisting entries is quite a drastic step only performed by the stack exchange community team. But we can contact them should we need to if they don't pick up on such issues in meta (but we're all sorted here now anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ux-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-design) has been burned and blacklisted.

There's some cleanup work to do: [untagged](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Comment: Thanks :) I also see this is no longer a 'suggested' tag.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it should be removed because it doesn't add anything. On-topic questions here are about UX anyway, so [ux-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-design) is unneeded.

Answer (score 5):

The only reason to keep it that I can see is to differentiate these questions from ones dealing with ux research... But we don't really get a whole lot of those. I say nuke it.